# Outputting to a stdout and a file with cout, cerr, clog, or even user defined ostreams

Tags: c++, io

## The Question

I have been looking for a way to implement a way to have cout, cerr, etc output to the console and to a file, unfortunately my knowledge on buffers is quite lacking, so a detailed explanation of what everything is doing would be very nice.

The most impressive thing I can do is:

```
//Includes not shown

std::ofstream file ("out.txt");
std::streambuf* fileSb = file.rdbuf();
cout.rdbuf(fileSb);
```

But even with my limited knowledge I have some idea based on the research I have done on what the structure will look like:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "dualBuffer.h"

int main () {
    std::ofstream file ("out.txt");
    dualBuffer(cout, file);
    std::cout << "Hellow world!" << std::endl; //This outputs to console and file 
}
```

#### dualBuffer.h

```
#include <iostream> 

class dualBuffer : public streambuf /*Maybe ostream as well ????*/ {
public:
    dualBuffer (std::ostream & os1, std::ostream& os2)
        : *os1b ( os1.rdbuf() )
        , *os1b ( os2.rebuf() )
        { }
    //Another constructor if streambuf* is passed instead
private:
    std::streambuf *os1b, *os2b;
}
//May have typos or bugs
```

One of the requirements is that it is all built on top of the standard library nothing external or OS dependent, the other is that I want it so that cout has the same property in every single part of the program after dualBuffer constructor has done its thing

Comment: You probably want to look into [Boost.IOStreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement change the normal behavior of cout, which makes the codes confusing.
Why not use another class to do this.Like this :

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

class GeneralOStream
{
public:
    GeneralOStream(std::ostream& stdStream, std::ostream& fileStream)
        :_stdStream(stdStream)
        , _fileStream(fileStream)
    {
    }

    template<typename T>
    friend GeneralOStream& operator << (GeneralOStream& stream, const T& t);

private:
    std::ostream& _stdStream;
    std::ostream& _fileStream;
};

template<typename T>
GeneralOStream& operator << (GeneralOStream& stream, const T& t)
{
    stream._stdStream << t;
    stream._fileStream << t;

    return stream;
}

int main() 
{
    std::ofstream file("out.txt");
    GeneralOStream gos(std::cout, file);
    std::cout << "Hellow world!" << std::endl; //This outputs to console and file 
}
```

Comment: I was originally intending on modifying the cout, etc
but i guess i could just do that
Thanks

Comment: Finally got around to implementing it and it's not outputting to a file  
May be a fault due to copying and modifying, or in the thing itself

Comment: not a fault in the sense you are thing, more like not working as its intended cause it outputs to the screen fine but not to a file, however a file is created by ofstream  

EDIT: more detail

Comment: Okay fixed the problem. No problems now